# incompatible data types: boolean and int

Tags: java

I get this error when I try to compile.

imcomparible types: boolean and int

```
result= (result) && (found_list[i] !=0);
```

Why do I get this error? How do I fix it??

Comment: What are the types of found_list?

Comment: boolean[] found_list = new boolean[num_of_rotors];

Comment: If result is of type int, there is an error since (result) && (found_list[i] !=0) is a boolean expression.  Also (result) would be wrong.  Which is the type of result?

Comment: Boolean is a datatype that takes only two values

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to compare `found_list[i]` of type boolean to `0` of type int

Then change

```
result= (result) && (found_list[i] !=0);
```

to

```
result= (result) && (found_list[i]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Since found_list[] is a boolean array, you can't compare with an int value. `(found_list[i] !=0)` is wrong.

The way to do it would be:

```
result= (result) && (found_list[i]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Unlike languages c, c++ and many other, `0` & `1` **aren't** `false` & `true` in java.

This is a common mistake. Also, doing checking for something like `boolean != false` is the exact same as checking if `boolean` is true. i.e.

```
if(b != false)
```

is same as

```
if(b)
```

So, you can do

```
result = result && found_list[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

Boolean takes only True of False as values and nothing else like other datatypes such as int,long,double,short etc...

Hence if result is a boolean the value you store in it should also be a boolean that is either True or False.

```
result= (result) && (found_list[i] !=0);
```

Here **(result) is either True of False**.If you have just intialized it and left like

Boolean result;

Then the value here is false.Else if you have modified it somewhere before this it would be the respective value.

Now  (found_list[i] !=0); is a wrong way of coding. If found_list[] is a boolean, you cannot compare it with a int value(0 in this case).

**What you or trying to do here is 
true/false!=0 which can not be compared.**

Hence you are getting this error.You can instead change it to

```
result= ((result) && (found_list[i]))
```